# ¿Cómo hacer para que las Áreas en ASP.net MVC utilicen el Layout global?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo el siguiente escenario:

```
/Views/Shared/_Layout;
/Areas/Area1/Views/ControllerName/Index
/Areas/Area2/Views/ControllerName/Index
/Areas/Area3/Views/ControllerName/Index
...
/Areas/AreaN/Views/ControllerName/Index
```

¿Existe alguna manera de forzar a todas las áreas para que utilicen como base el Layout general definido en la primera línea del código de ejemplo de arriba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro pe maaaano! Vamos por partes, primero necesitamos:

```
_ViewStart.cshtml
```

Esto va en la carpeta de `Views` de cada área, de esta manera:

```
/Areas/Area1/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml
```

Luego editamos el archivo para que apunte al layout global:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Éxitos y bendiciones :D